# how detect firebase changing when child of child 's add value

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBolT.png)

this realtime firebase state

if [55] add -Lenua~~ as child

how [22] detect changed DB?

in other word, detecting [22]'s direct child( ex [55],[33]) change is OK 
but,
How does parent detect the change of the child's child ?

parent = [22] , child = [33], [55] , child's child = [-Lenua~~], [-Paea~~] –

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add the JSON file or at least a screenshot of it.

Comment: i add image of firebase db

Comment: Ok but please rephrase the question.

Comment: complete edit question

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: How does parent detect the change of the child's child ?

Comment: parent = [22] , child = [33], [55] , child's child = [-Lenua~~], [-Paea~~]